# GDM3 issues on 23.10

Tags: xorg, wayland, gdm, 23.10

I recently updated to 23.0 and then 23.10 (hoping it would fix the issue).

When the OS gets to the screen which would normally be the DM login, it just gives the vague "Oh no!" Message. I've tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop to no avail.

I've also installed LightDM, which allows me to log into Ubuntu desktop (Wayland or x11) and after logging in, I get the same "Oh No!" Error.

I've been able to sign into unity, but it doesn't seem like it's working, as there's no toolbars or keyboard shortcuts.

I'm at a loss, and any help debugging these vague error messages would be super helpful!

Other things that could be causing issues would be having recently attempted a sway install and also a hyprland install (I realize this is not meant for gnome, so I did try uninstalling it).

I have an AMD Radeon RX 5xx series card of that's useful info

Additional info:
journalctl shows an unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.shell.desktop. warning says it exited with code 127.